# Node tagged with more than one taxonomy, how to keep expanded the specific taxonomy menu the user has used to reach a node

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have nodes associated to more than one taxonomy vocabulary, so the same node can be listed/reached in different ways, for example:

Brand > Family line > model > NODES

Veicles > category > NODES

e.g.

Ferrari > Top-Luxury > Testarossa > NODES > NODE-A

Cars > Supercars > NODES > NODE-A

By Design every node can have only and only one URL: it's ok for me (and for SEO)

Now I have created different taxonomy menus (based on the above taxonomies) to retrieve nodes in different ways:

**TAXONOMY MENU A:** Ferrari > Top-Luxury > Testarossa > NODE-A

**TAXONOMY MENU B:** Cars > Supercars > NODE-A

**The question is:** is there a way to keep expanded the specific taxonomy menu the user has used to reach the node?

So:

if user has reached NODE-A trough MENU A then MENU A is showed and expanded in the page

if user has reached NODE-A trough MENU B then MENU B is showed and expanded in the page

Is there a way to accomplish this?

May be using SESSION variables? (ref: http://drupal.org/node/1443210 )

Thank you very much for any help

Answer (score 2):

I've done this in my modules [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) implementation by using sessions, [menu_get_object](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) and [menu_tree_set_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree_set_path/7). Here's some example code showing my general approach:

```
function mymodule_init() {
  // Save the active path for users when on taxonomy term pages.
  if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && arg(2)) {
    $_SESSION['mymodule_path'] = $_GET['q'];
  }
  // The user is on a node page.
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1)) {
    $node = menu_get_object();
    // Assuming all the nodes in the taxonomy menu are of the same specific type.
    if ($node->type == 'mynodetype') {
      if (isset($_SESSION['mymodule_path'])) {
        menu_tree_set_path('menu-mymenu', $_SESSION['mymodule_path']);
      }
    }
  }
```